# Connecting scss to css with Live Sass Compile

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm using the 'Live Sass Compile' extension on Visual Studio Code.

What is the right path to connect `css2.scss` to `css2.js`?

[image]

[image]

[Maybe a useful article](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want css2.scss to compile into the parent folder as css2.css

Try setting the savePath using the relative path notation like, and move one level up with ../

`savePath: "~/../"`

Note: It would be good to have all the scss in a separate folder, there are a few .scss file in parent css folder.

Comment: That hasn't worked although I wouldn't be surprised if it's because I need to refresh something... What does `~` mean? The current folder the `.scss` is in?

Comment: "~" - denotes relative to every sass file. Instead than taking a specific path, if you want the generated css to be relative to each scss file's path.

Comment: Does this save path persist for **every single** `.scss` file we make that connects to a `.css`? Even if we make new connections in different projects?